# packaging webservice application with electron

Tags: python, electron, nsis, electron-builder

I have an electron application that must be used with a python webserver backend on the host.

For convenience, the python webserver has been packaged with cx_freeze and is now available as .exe windows program.

My problem is now to know howto launch this webserver.exe application when electron application launches, and stopped when user quits application.

Comment: How is this NSIS related?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to start it (under win32 platform):

```
function createWindow() {
// launch webserver
var child_process = require('child_process');
var child = child_process.spawn('webserver.exe',[],{
  'cwd' : 'some folder'  
  });


// ...
 // mainwindow creation 

}
```